# Convert .264 to .ts using ffmpeg library

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, h.264, libav

I'm currently working on converting h.264 elementary stream (file with postfiix .264) to transport stream (file with postfix .ts). I have finished the conversion successfully using ffmpeg command line "ffmpeg -i in.264 -an -vcodec copy -f mpegts out.ts".

Now I want to implement this conversion using my own C++ code, by calling ffmpeg's libraries. I have downloaded precompiled ffmpeg libraries (libavcodec, libavformat etc). My input h.264 is prerecorded file, not live stream, and so as my output .ts file. So my question is which functions in the library should I call to implement the conversion?

Answer (score 1):

You will see an example file named ffmpeg.c after you install ffmpeg in Linux. There are many options to set the decoding parameters in this file e.g. opt_audio_codec, opt_video_codec, opt_audio_rate, opt_video_rate, opt_default etc. Just set the necessary parameters from your command(-i in.264 -an -vcodec copy -f mpegts out.ts) using appropriate functions before calling "transcode" or "av_encode" function from "main" function of ffmpeg.c file.

Comment: So it seems like I don't need to call the specific coding/muxing function that defined in the library. I just need to call the function in avcodec.h or avformat.h as an interface, and they will implicitly all relevant function to implement the conversion. Is that correct?

Comment: @summerlismile yeap, just call "transcode" or "av_encode" (in earlier version) setting appropriate parameters as I described above. This is not so hard. If you look into ffmpeg.c file, I hope you will understand everything more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

It's not as simple as list the library calls.  Here is an old [tutorial](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/) that will help you get started reading the input file.  There is also an example called decoding_encoding.c that is included with the ffmpeg source.  These should help you get started.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dan. Yes, I'm currently reading the Dranger's turotial, it's a little bit outdated, but still helpful. By the way, I also see an example called muxing.c that included with the ffmpeg source file. I think the conversion from h.264 elementary stream to transport stream is more muxing than coding/decoding. So I should refer to the muxing.c code. Am I right?

Comment: @summerlismile I don't think you need to look into muxing.c file. You already have the command (-i in.264 -an -vcodec copy -f mpegts out.ts). Just see how to convert this command to code using opt_audio_codec, opt_video_codec, opt_audio_rate, opt_video_rate, opt_default etc. functions and then call "transcode" or "av_encode" function in ffmpeg.c file. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do it in your own code. You can just spawn the ffmpeg process programatically instead. Use `CreateProcess` on Windows, or `spawn` on Linux.